# Set default value for all column of a kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid.I am binding data source with a List (C#).Generate 50 columns.I want to have my Grid every column with fixed width.Like width 150 px.How could I set default Column width for my grid ?

```
$("#detailsRevenueGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {

        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "GetDetailsRevenueReportData",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                if (operation != "read") {
                    return kendo.stringify(data.models);
                }

            }
        },

        serverPaging: false,
        pageSize: 10,

        batch: true,

        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.errors + "grid");
        }
    },

    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true
    },
    sortable: true,
    scrollable:true,
    autoBind: false,
    resizable: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Kendo grid documentation here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.width) for that. To do it, you have to define every column that you want in the grid. Here is their example (in case the link breaks later) with a couple of modifications:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
 <script>
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
   columns: [
     { field: "name", width: "200px", title: "Name" },
     { field: "age", width: 75, title: "Age" }
   ],
   dataSource: [
     { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
     { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
   ]
 });
 </script>
```

`field` is the name of the property in the data object you are binding to the grid. You can also set the title, the width, and a number of other options described in the docs.

**Update**

After seeing your comment, I think you can do what you want with a CSS style:

```
#grid col, #grid td, #grid th {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Where `#grid` is the ID of your grid container div. Make sure to remove any width settings from the `columns` property as they will most likely override the CSS.

Comment: Yes I know about that.Actually I am using Data source & not specified the Columns seperatlly,rather then I directly showing a list into grid.I want to specify Column width 150px for each generated column.automatically.Could I make myself clear?Thanks in advance for any help